# How to require PHP Mailparse into a script

Tags: php, parsing, email, include, require

I installed PHP's Mailparse extension (PECL) onto my VPS.
Now I want to make a script with it but have no idea how to include it into my script.

`dl()` does not work on my server so I'd need `require()` or `require_once()`

Path to PHP is /usr/bin/php

As far as I know it's likely something like `require_once("Mail/[something here]")` but I cannot find any information on it.

Comment: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/mailparse.installation.php

Comment: I already installed it, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary extensions do not need to be enabled in scripts. They just extend PHP with new functions and methods, so you can use it like it is part of PHP itself. However if you rely on 3rd party extension it's good idea to check if it is installed otherwise your script will fail with syntax errors. Use [get_loaded_extensions()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) and check the result for presence of whatever extension you require.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't like I enabled it in php.ini.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is stated in the link in my comment I posted under your question. You know the one you were replying to saying: "I already installed it"